# Save unknown generic type to collection and restore specific type

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to generics in Java.

I need to save various instances of generic class `GameRule<T>` with values of type `T` to collection for later bulk use in method with signature:

```
public <T> void applyGameRule(GameRule<T>, T value)
```

How can I do that?

I have tried making wrapper like this:

```
public class GameRuleHolder {

private Object gameRule;
private String gameRuleType;
private Object value;
private String valueType;

public <T> GameRuleHolder(GameRule<T> gameRule, T value) {
    this.gameRule = gameRule;
    this.gameRuleType = gameRule.getClass().getName();
    this.value = value;
    this.valueType = value.getClass().getName();
}
// getters, setters ...
```

I stored GameRules to this wrapper and saved them in Set.

but when I try to call needed method like this:

```
setGameRule(Class.forName(gameRule.getGameRuleType()).cast(gameRule.getGameRule()), Class.forName(gameRule.getValueType()).cast(gameRule.getValue()));
```

I get this error in IDE:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Can't you just pass to GameRule<?>?

Comment: @PrashantPandey What do you mean?